# How can I solve an error after installing RStudio

Tags: r

I downloaded Rstudio and installed it on my laptop. When I want to open Rstudio I see the below message:
The program can't start because api-ms-win-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Could you please help me how I can solve this error and work with RStudio? 
(I have R on my laptop and work with it without any problem.)

Comment: Hi vahid, welcome to Stack Overflow. This website is centered on answering programing questions. Your question is instead about technical support, and thus isn't suited to this website. Your question could *potentially* be on-topic for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). Nonetheless, have you tried [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I did not have Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 installed. I downloaded and installed Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015. Now the mentioned error is fixed. I can work with RStudio.